# Do these parts fit my Giant Escape 2 2018?

Tags: parts, upgrades, groupsets, giant

This is my bike [Giant escape 2 2018](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/escape-2-2018)

I want to change the groupset (for fun) for this one [aliexpress link,](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32852030348.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.49a654e9YfWIrp&algo_pvid=31b523ee-6b65-440d-b046-b3bfeecac66a&algo_expid=31b523ee-6b65-440d-b046-b3bfeecac66a-1&btsid=0ab6f82315887421930674181e4891&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) Basically it's a Shimano Deore M6000 2x10 groupset (without the brakes)

I'm almost sure that it will be compatible but I don't want to spend the money before making the purchase so. Can you guys share your knowledge, is this compatible with my bike ?

Also, I think I need to buy a new freehub, do I?

Comment: I suggest you check the price locally for the same parts, and see if the difference is worth doing.  Aliexpress is not a reseller of shimano, so these could be original, or they could be rejects, or complete knockoffs.   Its up to you to decide if the difference makes this worth doing at all.   There are bike parts resellers that stand by their guarantees.  Aliexpress sellers are a very mixed bag.

Comment: Yeah I've been looking for local sellers for months but the market here in Peru is way overpriced and scarce since half the stuff I want I can't find. Also I can't find any world shipping sellers, chainreaction is really nice but they don't offer this or any similar groupset. I'm a little bit scared also about aliexpress but I had good experience so far and I think I'll take the risk in this case unless I find something better

Comment: its a lot of money to gamble.  Set your worst case expectation of complete loss, and don't overspend ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think that would work

The Escape is Altus 8 speed with rim brakes. For a 10 speed replacement group you will not need to mess with the hub, a 10 speed cassette will fit

The bottom bracket shell is threaded as the Escape has a cartridge BB. You'll obviously need to replace that with a external bearing unit. It does not matter if the shell is 68 or 73mm width.

The rear spacing is going to be 135mm. A Deore crank compatible with a 68 or 73mm threaded bottom bracket shell will have an acceptable chainline.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still learning so just to be sure: what do you mean with an external bearing unit? is the shimano SM-BB52 a cartridge with external bearing unit?

Comment: The SM-BB52 external bearing bottom bracket is what you need and it’s included in the set you’ve linked.  You’ll need a special tool to remove the currently installed cartridge bottom bracket and another tool to install the new external bearings.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for the tools since I've never messed with bottom brackets yet. One other thing I realized is the front derailleur included with the linked groupset is bottom swing, and I saw my bike has a top swing so I'm contacting the seller to see If they can offer the top swing one for me